# Use scope attribute of directive as class name in ngClass

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, ng-class

I want to use a scope attribute of a directive as the class name in ngClass

```
someModule.directive("someDirective", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            styleClass: '@',
        },
        replace: true,
        template: "<li ng-class='{'{{styleClass}}:true'}' />"
    }
}
```

I've tried other syntax of ngClass as well but this doesn't work either (I added a `$scope.dummy = true` for this)

```
template: "<li ng-class=\"{true: '{{styleClass}}'}[dummy]\" />"
```

Is there a right way of doing this ??

Comment: This should be `template: "<li ng-class='{true:styleClass}' />"`. Can you check

Comment: I'd go with:

`template: function(elem, attr) {
  return "<li ng-class='{" + attr.styleClass + ": true}' />"
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no condition in your ng-class expression, you can simply use class in your template:

```
template: "<li class='{{styleClass}}'/>"
```

Here's an example in plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/YrqMeAIbaekeH8PFlQIg?p=preview

Comment: I know this is a pretty old question, but i use hamlJS and writing curly braces inside any attribute gives an error, is there any way around it?

Comment: @Zoheiry I never worked with hamlJS. You can create a new question for this.